# Align image on top in Custom ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I am using `ViewPager` from [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) to load images to my app. This is the `TouchImageView.java` which responsible for the loading of image.

```
float redundantXSpace = viewWidth - (scaleX * drawableWidth);
        float redundantYSpace = viewHeight - (scaleY * drawableHeight);
        matchViewWidth = viewWidth - redundantXSpace;
        matchViewHeight = viewHeight - redundantYSpace;
        if (!isZoomed() && !imageRenderedAtLeastOnce) {
            //
            // Stretch and center image to fit view
            //
            matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY);
            matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace / 2, redundantYSpace / 2);
            normalizedScale = 1;

        } else {
            //
            // These values should never be 0 or we will set viewWidth and viewHeight
            // to NaN in translateMatrixAfterRotate. To avoid this, call savePreviousImageValues
            // to set them equal to the current values.
            //
            if (prevMatchViewWidth == 0 || prevMatchViewHeight == 0) {
                savePreviousImageValues();
            }

            prevMatrix.getValues(m);
```

The code load my images on vertical center. What I want to achieve is to load the images on vertical top. If I change the `matchViewHeight = viewHeight - redundantYSpace;` to `matchViewHeight = viewHeight;`, the image will fill the entire height. What modification should I made to make to align on vertical top?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY);
matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace / 2, 0);
```

postTranslate - moved the image. You do not need to move along the y axis for align on top.

For align on bottom:

```
matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY);
matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace / 2, redundantYSpace );
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only work on sliding the `ViewPager`. After I release it from slide, the image will move back to center vertical.

Comment: try replace in method `setZoom(float scale, float focusX, float focusY, ScaleType scaleType)`
 `m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] = -((focusY * getImageHeight()) - (viewHeight * 0.5f));` on `m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] =0;`. And check other place which changed matrix.

Comment: Still not working. The code seems to be complicated. Anyway, I'm giving you upvote as appreciation.